# AngularJS return value from factory to controller out of Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTTP request setup as a promise in a .factory and would like to send the result to a controller. However I am stuck with getting the data out of promise and into somewhere I can use it.

.controller

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Main, User) {
    $scope.feedResult = function () {
        var feeds = [];
        return Main.feed(key).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1)
            {
                feeds.push(data[i]);
            }
            return feeds;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("This was an error back from the server");
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
    }();
})
```

and the .factory

```
        feed: function (token) {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://myserver.com/feed',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                    auth_code: token,
                    per_page: 10
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1)
                {
                    feeds.push(data[i]);
                }
                return feeds;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("This was an error back from the server");
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            });
        },
```

Mo matter how I seem to try putting things into a scope I always seem to end up with the promise object. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The success or error method will always return a  promise (it wraps your return value into a new promise). You shoudl set the value on the scope from within the success/error callback:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Main, User) {
    $scope.feedResult = [];
    Main.feed(key).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1)
        {
             $scope.feedResult.push(data[i]);
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("This was an error back from the server");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.feedResult = data;
    });
})
```